# Django Autocomplete Light is not working with Django Filters

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to use **Django autocomplete light** with **Django filters**. I've written the following codes. And also tried different solutions, but nothing is working for me. An empty list is shown in the dropdown.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    # ............
]
```

**filters.py**

```
class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    user = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        label='Username', queryset=User.objects.all(),
        empty_label="All",
        # lookup_expr='icontains',
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='user:search')
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    UserList,
    UserSearchAutocomplete,
)

app_name = 'user'

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', UserList.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('search/', UserSearchAutocomplete.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from dal import autocomplete


class UserSearchAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = User.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(first_name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs
```

**templates/list.html**

```
{{ filter.form.user }}
```

Help me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than handling with django, I would recommend using JS to handle this issue.

Comment: An empty list is shown when url parameter in `ModelSelect2` does not work properly.